# Multi-Target Tracking Filters

Tags: kalman-filter, particle-filter

I am trying to solve a multi-target tracking problem, which is in some parts different to some filters I have already researched such as the PHD filter. I am asking for advise which filters to start looking at given that:

- I need to track multiple but a known and fixed number of targets (there are no deaths/births)
- There is a data association problem between the measurements I am observing and the targets to track
- The measurements I am observing are correlated, but conditionally (on the state) independent
- My system (measurement and state-evolution) is non-linear but with additive Gaussian noise

I have already found several references including those [here-in](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28518/tracking-and-data-association-with-kalman-filters), but I'm lacking the general overview of which filters have which assumptions or requirements.

Answer (score 1):

(this question may be more suitable in dsp.stackexchange)
This is my first answering attempt to a question, so...

> I need to track multiple but a known and fixed number of targets (there are no deaths/births)

PHD filter, as you may know, is based on Random Finite Sets, and it handles object birth/death cases, so you don't need to know the number of targets. If you know the number of targets, you can use "multiple single target tracking filters".

> There is a data association problem between the measurements I am observing and the targets to track

This is also known as "measurement-to-track association" problem (which can be handled independently of the tracking filter) and Probabilistic Data Association Filter (PDAF) [[1](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=5338565)] or Joint Probabilistic Data Association Filter [[2](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=6493379)] may suit your needs. [[2](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=6493379)] is actually proposed for the case when there are multiple measurements from a single target. But, depending on the existence of clutter/false alarms or missed detections.

> My system (measurement and state-evolution) is non-linear but with additive Gaussian noise

Widely used non-linear filters are Extended Kalman filter (EKF), Unscented Kalman filter (UKF), (maybe) Converted Measurements Kalman Filter (CMKF). So, you might look into these.

In my opinion, you need to find a "suitable" measurement-to-track association algorithm for your problem. The other requirements you mentioned above can be found in almost all "classical" (I mean Kalman based) filters. In addition, your first requirement simplifies your tracking problem.